# Checking if database is already filled

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if a field is already filled with data in the database. If is is I want to update the information but if it's empty I want to insert the information into the database. But it doesn't work now :

```
$info = $_POST['info'];
$gebruiker = $_POST['gebruiker'];
$getnamequery = mysql_query("SELECT fysionummer  
                             FROM algemene_info WHERE fysionummer = '$gebruiker'");
$result = mysql_query($getnamequery) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($gebruiker === $row) { 

    $sql = 'UPDATE algemene_info
            SET omschrijving=$info
        WHERE fysionummer=$gebruiker';


    echo "Het update van de algemene informatie is geslaagd!";

} else {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO algemene_info (`info_id`, `omschrijving`, `fysionummer`)
            VALUES (NULL, '$info', '$gebruiker')") or die (mysql_error());

    echo "Het toevoegen van de oefening is geslaagd!";

}
```

Comment: See INSERT... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension has been deprecated for quite some time now in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$info = $_POST['info'];
$gebruiker = $_POST['gebruiker'];
$getnamequery = mysql_query("SELECT fysionummer  FROM algemene_info WHERE fysionummer = '$gebruiker'");
$result = mysql_query($getnamequery) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($gebruiker == $row['fysionummer']) {
$sql = 'UPDATE algemene_info
         SET omschrijving=$info
          WHERE fysionummer=$gebruiker';
echo "Het update van de algemene informatie is geslaagd!";
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO algemene_info (`info_id`, `omschrijving`, `fysionummer`)
    VALUES (NULL, '$info', '$gebruiker')") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Het toevoegen van de oefening is geslaagd!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HI Complete solution as follows,

  $info = $_POST['info'];
 $gebruiker = $_POST['gebruiker'];
   $getnamequery = mysql_query("SELECT fysionummer  FROM algemene_info WHERE fysionummer = '$gebruiker'");
      $result = mysql_query($getnamequery) or die(mysql_error());

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num != "")
{
     $sql = 'UPDATE algemene_info
     SET omschrijving=$info
      WHERE fysionummer=$gebruiker';
     mysql_query($sql) or die("!query");
    echo "Het update van de algemene informatie is geslaagd!";
}

 else
         {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO algemene_info (`info_id`, `omschrijving`, `fysionummer`)
 VALUES (NULL, '$info', '$gebruiker')") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Het toevoegen van de oefening is geslaagd!";
        }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation along with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$info = $_POST['info'];
$gebruiker = $_POST['gebruiker'];
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT *  
                             FROM algemene_info WHERE fysionummer = '$gebruiker'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$qry = "INSERT INTO algemene_info (`info_id`, `omschrijving`, `fysionummer`) VALUES ({{$row['info_id']}},'$info', '$gebruiker') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE omschrijving='$info'";
mysqli_query($qry);
```